# Intermittent box appearing over characters when converting MS Access Report to PDF using VBA

Tags: vba, ms-access, pdf

This is my first time on any forum like this, so please excuse me if I don't follow protocols.

I am using **MS Access 365** to produce a report using VBA, via the `OutputTo` command as per below:-

```
DoCmd.OutputTo acOutputReport, "rptCancellationLetterPayment", acFormatPDF, strFolderPath & "\Policy\" & strReportName, False
```

Intermittently the report will convert, but with what appears to be a box over the top of some letters (always the same letters in the past) the area that is affected is a text box

***Example***

[image]

Today this has occurred for the first time in a data field.

We are using Segoe UI font.

Thanks in advance for any assistance you can provide.

Comment: Which letters? Does this happen with other fonts? Does it happen with same file on another computer? I cannot replicate issue. Did you mean "dat**e** field"? This is not an issue with VBA so there is no relevant code to analyze.

Comment: This is happening on M, N, I & P mostly. It has happened with other fonts, but nowhere near as frequently. Yes, it does happen on other PC's, but does not appear to happen when i open the report manually and print to local PDF  printer. No i didn't mean "Date Field", i was trying to distinguish between text box and data field.

Comment: I don't get the distinction between 'textbox' and 'data field'. Aren't textboxes bound to fields? What is a 'data field' on a report?

Comment: Within the report is have "permanent text" similar to a standard letter, which then has data fields which pulls from the database things like name, address ect. The text boxes are not bound fields.

Comment: I still cannot replicate. Does it happen with text in label control?